# Визуализация бинарного дерева

Tags: c#, бинарное-дерево

Преподаватель задал реализовать визуализацию дерева, однако мою визуализацию он таки не принял. Вопрос: Что не так с этим деревом?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace tree
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] arrayS;
        int n, m;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
        arrayS = Console.ReadLine().ToArray();
        arrayS = SortArray(arrayS);
        n = getN(arrayS.Length);
        m = (int)Math.Pow(2, n - 1) * 2 + 1;
        char[,] tree = new char[n, m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                tree[i, j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        tree[0, m / 2] = arrayS[0];
        int position = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (tree[i, j] != ' ' && tree[i, j] != '_')
                {
                    if (position < arrayS.Length)
                    {
                        tree[i + 1, j - (int)Math.Pow(2, n - 2 - i)] = arrayS[position++];
                        for (int k = j - (int)Math.Pow(2, n - 2 - i); k < j; k++)
                            tree[i, k] = '_';
                    }
                    if(position<arrayS.Length) {
                        tree[i + 1, j + (int)Math.Pow(2, n - 2 - i)] = arrayS[position++];
                        for (int k = j + 1; k <= j + (int)Math.Pow(2, n - 2 - i); k++)
                            tree[i, k] = '_';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        // 54637
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(tree[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    private static int getN(int length)
    {
        if (length == 1) return 1;
        else return 1 + getN(length / 2);
    }

    private static char[] SortArray(char[] arr)
    {
        char min = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        { 
            min = arr[i];
            for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (min > arr[j])
                {
                    min = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = min;
                }
            }
        }

        char[] array = new char[arr.Length];
        int position = arr.Length / 2-1;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i+=2, position--)
        {
            array[i] = arr[position];
        }
        position = arr.Length / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i+=2, position++)
        {
            array[i] = arr[position];
        }
        return array;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Так может быть у преподавателя спросить, чем ему не нравится дерево?

Comment: @dDevil У вас как в левом так и в правом поддереве есть значения как больше так и меньше N. Дерево предполагает, что с одной стороны на любую глубину все значения меньше чем на вершине, а справа больше

Comment: @mike т.е если исправить этот недочет, то данную реализацию можно считать визуализацией бинарного дерева?

Comment: @dDevil Ну лично я бы считал, если дерево правильно построено, то любой читаемый внешний вид меня строил. Но я же не ваш препод :)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо огромное за ответ

Comment: @Mike преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Форматировать с `<br>` не нужно, в markdown есть способ проще — двойной абзац. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51861, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/478376/revisions

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо, обязательно учту. И победы на выборах! Я с Вами!))

Comment: @dDevil: о, спасибо )) Вот ещё вдогонку статейка про markdown: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас как в левом так и в правом поддереве есть значения, как больше так и меньше N. Дерево предполагает, что с одной стороны на любую глубину все значения меньше чем на вершине, а справа больше.

Comment: Нет такого определения дерева. Дерево - это связный граф, у которого нет циклов. Данная визуализация полностью подходит под определение двоичного (бинарного) дерева. А преподаватель, вероятно, хочет увидеть двоичное дерево поиска. Про разницу я писал в ответе на  [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478436/177373).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int Print(Node node, int x, int y)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(node.Value);

        var loc = y;

        if (node.Right != null)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 2, y);
            Console.Write("--");
            y = Print(node.Right, x + 4, y);
        }

        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            while (loc <= y)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, loc + 1);
                Console.Write(" |");
                loc++;
            }
            y = Print(node.Left, x, y + 2);
        }

        return y;
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]