# Бинарное дерево

Tags: бинарное-дерево

Требуется реализовать бинарное дерево, НО:
Обязательное ли условие, чтобы правая крайняя сторона с корня увеличивалась до **максимума**, а левая крайняя сторона уменьшалась до **минимума**?(см. на приложенное изображение) 
Интернет перерыл, но прямым текстом это нигде не написано, но на одних визуализациях это условие выполняется, а на других нет. [image: Дерево]

**Обновлено**:
Можно ли данную реализацию считать бинарным деревом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @alexander-barakin ну, если вам проще себе усложнять жизнь, то пожалуйста

Comment: Если говорить о дереве поиска (моё название: упорядоченное дерево), то так и будет (слева меньшие числа, справа - большие). В произвольном бинарном дереве
это условие не обязано выполняться. Советую Вам поиграть с моей программой Trees.exe (https://soft.softodrom.ru/ap/Trees-Portable-p19987), я писал её для старшеклассников, чтобы показать наглядно работу с бинарным деревом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Определения

Определение бинарного дерева:<sup>(1)</sup>

> Дерево, в котором каждая вершина имеет не более двух потомков,
>   называется *бинарным*, в противном случае будем дерево называть
>   *произвольным*.

Определение бинарного дерева поиска:<sup>(2)</sup>

> Будем называть бинарное дерево *деревом поиска*, если для любой вершины
>   ключ этой вершины не меньше ключа любой вершины левого поддерева и
>   строго меньше ключа любой вершины правого поддерева

Ссылки:

> <sup>(1)</sup> В.Д.Валединский, Ю.Н.Пронкин Вычислительные системы и
>   программирование, Схемы хранения данных (Москва, 2006 г.) стр 67
>
> <sup>(2)</sup> В.Д.Валединский, Ю.Н.Пронкин Вычислительные системы и
>   программирование, Схемы хранения данных (Москва, 2006 г.) стр 74

---

Изображение на рисунке терминала является бинарным деревом, но не бинарном деревом поиска, так как нет алфавитного или какого-нибудь другого, заранее обговорённого, порядка

Comment: @dDevil, я обновил ответ. Возможно, это будет для вас полезным.

Comment: спасибо, но Вы ранее дали довольно исчерпывающий ответ. Вопросов у меня на эту тему больше нет:) Спасибо

Comment: @dDevil пожалуйста. Я просто заметил, что определение в русской википедии не совсем корректно и решил написать определение из правильной литературы.